# About ubuntu browser certificate pem

Tags: firefox, users, certificates

On an Ubuntu machine with Firefox installed, we have a certificate file stored in a local directory. We want new users who log in to automatically have this certificate installed in their Firefox browsers without any manual steps required. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves a lot up to interpretation, but if I interpreted it correctly I believe you can add the certificate in question to a non-home folder where firefox looks for certificates:

```
    /usr/lib/mozilla/certificates
    /usr/lib64/mozilla/certificates
    ~/.mozilla/certificates
```

So depending on your installation either in the `/usr/lib/mozilla` or `/usr/lib64/mozilla` directory. Source: https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/AddRootToFirefox

Comment: This might not work with snapped Firefox nowadays.  Double check that this works with snapped Firefox which is the default now in Ubuntu.